# Has anyone wrote a SQL Azure data provider for Graffiti CMS 1.3

Tags: azure-sql-database, graffiticms

Is anybody using SQL Azure with Graffiti CMS. If so how do you add SQL Azure as your DB for Graffiti CMS 1.3?

Comment: No offense, but a free blogengine using a commercial cloud database while there's also VistaDB?! :)

But seriously, SQL Azure is just like SQL 2008 and as far as I know it supports that. So should work fine with SQL Azure, just a bit weirder connection strings. That's all I can do for you. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Graffiti CMS is not compatible with SQL Azure. Graffiti CMS 1.3 Beta supports SQL Server (2000, 2005, 2008), MySQL, and Access. Older versions also worked with VistaDB.

SQL Azure does not have the same feature set as SQL Server 2008 - it is a subset. So unfortunately the current Graffiti SQL Server data provider will not work on SQL Azure as it uses some of the unsupported things. For example ntext fields are used (to be compatible with older versions of SQL Server) and Azure only supports the newer varchar(max)/nvarchar(max).

It would be great to add SQL Azure support in the future though. :)